# Checking for current version of a PDF

Tags: pdf

Newbie to PDF.

The Problem:  We have thousands of copies PDF documents (forms people print and fill out)  that are downloaded regularly.  The "Last guy" put a URL on the PDF that the user could click" "Click here to see if the document is the current version".

A web server reads the parameters in the PDF and says 'yes' or 'no'.  It works pretty well.... if the user clicks it.

Is there anyway to fire the URL "On Open" of the pdf.  It would be ok if the PDF asked "Do you want to check to see if this document is current"

Comment: ...How is this a programming question? Might wanna try superuser

Comment: I would think that embedding a link on the fly in the PDF framework might possibly qualify

Comment: Since I understood nothing of what you just said, I'll stay out of this one :)

Comment: Probably a good Idea :)  FYI I got it working by using MBS and Xojo to do a simple find/replace on a place holder string using PDFlib.    (kind like using PDF Blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Document-level and a PageOpen action in PDF; you could therefore run the code associated to that link in one of these events.

However, it depends on how you view the PDF; the server's answer may or may not be understood by the PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to implement the external solution, i.e. some external script to check the date of the PDF document. 
Because once you are implementing scripts inside PDF you should check how it works in different PDF readers + you will need to rely on the pdf reader to execute the request + will need to maintain this script with the specialized knowledge required (how to embed scripts into PDF, write them etc).

It is much simplier to consider the PDF in the same way you would consider working with JPG or TIFF format: maybe some external file like document1.pdf.version that will store the version number or maybe just check the date time of the PDF file using file system info.